# Sending illustrated (Christmas card) emails

Tags: html, email

A client of ours wants to send all his clients an illustrated email for Christmas (yes, I know, and I know).

I know that email HTML is a very different beast to browser HTML, and there are a lot of things to bear in mind, but I don't know the best place to get this kind of information.

Does anyone know of any good sources, or can we get a list of best practices here?

**EDIT:** What about mail deployment? Is it worth using something like mailchimp? Anyone?

Comment: Are you sending the email programmatically? If so, which language are you using?

Comment: It doesn't have to be programmatically, but if it was, I'd probably use PHP. *Ducks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joel Spolsky tweeted [this link](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) (Blog Post titled ROCK SOLID HTML EMAILS) related to what you are asking. Haven't read it, but I guess it's good.

Comment: Looks good, thanks, but my god, that site works horribly in Chrome.

Comment: @Skilldrick: that's Chrome fail; it's not coping well with large areas of RGBA colour. My installation updated itself within the last day or two to version 4.0.249.30 (WinXP), and it now works perfectly well on 24ways.org, so you may want to check if there's an update pending for your copy.

Comment: @Nick - awesome, thanks. Chrome's on version 4 now?! Wow, that's more than Firefox... It must be good.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this article helps: [How to code HTML email newsletters](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters)